# set itemize symbol in a dash (setbeamertemplate)

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

I would like to set it in my beamertheme.sty so that when using enumerate or itemize, the symbols are dashes (--) by default. Unfortunately, I have not found a hint in the beamer documentation (chapter 12.1). Is there an additional package I can use for this, or have I missed an option?

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[option]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items][option]
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a compilable minimal working example so we can test possible solutions. Having to create a document and an itemisation just to be able to test a possible solution is really boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For itemize items you can set the templates like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}-}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subitem}-}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subsubitem}-}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```